Changing color of mesh in which shape keys is applied based in z direction for different areas in a mesh
I have a 3d mesh {I-beam} in blender which changes shape{bends} using  shape keys i want a way to make the color of the mesh change according to the z direction of the vertex of the mesh from their default position
it should look just like an fea animation just like how different parts of the beam changes color based on how much it is deflected from base shape

please add at least a link to a fea animation - you should not (!) prerequisite that everybody knows what fea animation is or looks like.

Do you mean  a tension map? That would indicate the stretch or compression of the surface at each point.. (if there is a straight section beyond the bend, it would show no stretch)

I added an image, the animation is made using shape keys just want to add colors which change with the amount of bend
